# How to query data in Cqrs cirqus

Tags: cqrs, cirqus

I look at the example [SqlsugCirqusDemo](https://github.com/d60/SqlsugCirqusDemo) using d60/Cirqus. I am wondering how to write the query part. For example, i want to get the order by orderid or list of order item in the orderby id

Comment: The given link is to a code base that does not define any read model handling, only sagas. Try doing some Googling for Query Handler pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you meant to link to [the Cirqus demo](https://github.com/d60/SqlsugCirqusDemo) :)

The approach I'm advocating people to use with Cirqus is to *only let Cirqus help you get the view data created and updated*, and then you just go and query it yourself - i.e. without any help from Cirqus.

Here's the reasoning:

If you let Cirqus help you create your view in some particular data store (e.g. SQL Server), it's probably because you want to use some feature of that data store (e.g. aggregations, joins, etc).

If Cirqus could help you also query that data, we would either have to 1) wrap each and every view data store in an API that targeted that data store, or 2) create some kind of abstraction that would work for all data stores (e.g. MongoDB, SQL Server, RavenDB, etc.).

1. Would be a lot of work and would provide no benefit, at least not with the mentioned data stores, because they all have nice .NET client APIs.
2. Would be silly, because how would you then use each data store's particular features?

Therefore my recommendation is this: Let Cirqus help you get your views in place, but when it's query time you just use whichever client API is available to you(*)

In [the demo project](https://github.com/d60/SqlsugCirqusDemo), the [`OrdersView`](https://github.com/d60/SqlsugCirqusDemo/blob/master/CirqusDemo/Views/OrdersView.cs) is stored in MongoDB (which is configured [here](https://github.com/d60/SqlsugCirqusDemo/blob/master/CirqusDemo/Program.cs#L15)) - in that case, I would configure my IoC container to inject an `IQueryable<OrdersView>` which it would resolve to `viewsMongoDatabase.GetCollection<OrdersView>(typeof(OrdersView).Name).AsQueryable()` - then I could do this:

```
var order = orders.First(o => o.Id == orderId);
```

which makes for some nice clean C# that is not at all polluted with persistence concerns and can be trivially unit tested if one desires.

---

(*) I can, however, recommend MongoDB as the view data store :) it enables storing some nice rich objects in the database, while allowing you to work with an `IQueryable<YourView>` when it's time to retrieve the data (although you need to use v. 1.10 or wait until version 2.1 of the MongoDB driver to do that - Cirqus' MongoDB integration currently uses 1.10)